# How to check if specific attribute exists in XML using Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I created a WPF program for communication with Arduinos.
In my app are multiple buttons to switch the ports.

To adress the buttons I created a simple format:

1. Every button has a specific name like "Button1"
2. Every Arduino in the system has an unique adress e.g. "2"
3. Then there´s the port of the Arduino e.g. "5"

Now I want to save the adress and the port number in a XML file using Linq:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <Buttondata btnName="Button1">
    <ardAdress>2</ardAdress>
    <pinNumber>5</pinNumber>
  </Buttondata>
  <Buttondata btnName="Button2">
    <ardAdress>3</ardAdress>
    <pinNumber>10</pinNumber>
  </Buttondata>
  <Buttondata btnName="Button3">
    <ardAdress>1</ardAdress>
    <pinNumber>6</pinNumber>
  </Buttondata>
</root>
...
```

This is the code for saving:

```
private void savetoXML()
  {
      XElement newElement = XElement.Load("Savedata.xml");
                newElement.Add(new XElement("Buttondata", 
                                              new XAttribute("btnName", ButtonName),
                                                   new XElement("ardAdress", result1),
                                                   new XElement("pinNumber", result2)));
      newElement.Save("Savedata.xml");
  }
```

This works fine so far, but now I want to check if the Button already exists and if so only change the adress and pin number.

I think about something like this:

```
private void savetoXML()
  {
    // check if button already exists
       if (button exists == true)
       {
         //change only adress and pin number of button
       }
       else (button exists == false)
       {
         //create new xml-Element for button
       }
  }
```

I've already tried it with a few code snippets but never got it to work properly.

The "ButtonName"-string tells me, which button has been pressed or rather needs to be updated.
Can anyone give me a tip how to adress the attribute "btnName" to see if "ButtonName" already exists?

Answer (score 0):

After some additional search I came up with following code:

```
private void SavetoXML()
        {
            XElement newElement = XElement.Load("Savedata.xml");
            
            var result = (from ele in newElement.Descendants("Buttondata")
                          .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("btnName") == ButtonName)
                          select ele).ToList();
          //if there´s an element in the list then override existing adress & pin
            if (result.Attributes("btnName").Count() == 1) 
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("existing");
                var items = from item in newElement.Elements("Buttondata")
                            where item != null && (item.Attribute("btnName").Value == ButtonName)
                            select item;

                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    //assign new value to the sub-element author
                    item.Element("ardAdress").Value = result1;
                    item.Element("pinNumber").Value = result2;
                    newElement.Save("Savedata.xml");
                }
            }
          //if there´s no element in the list then create new
            else if (result.Attributes("btnName").Count() == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("create new");
                newElement.Add(new XElement("Buttondata",
                                              new XAttribute("btnName", ButtonName),
                                                   new XElement("ardAdress", result1),
                                                   new XElement("pinNumber", result2)));
                newElement.Save("Savedata.xml");
            }
        }
```

Please note that I´m an absolute beginner. Maybe there is a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try following which puts results into a dictionary.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, Button> dict = doc.Descendants("Buttondata")
                .Select(x => new Button()
                {
                    name = (string)x.Attribute("btnName"),
                    addrress = (int)x.Element("ardAdress"),
                    number = (int)x.Element("pinNumber")
                }).GroupBy(x => x.name, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            Button button = dict["Button2"];
        }
    }
    public class Button
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int addrress { get; set; }
        public int number { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that, too!